# Autocomplete the input field from database in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I want to show the suggestion from the database in WordPress when the user enters in the field. I wrote below code, but it's not working exactly in which I want it to do.

actually i fetch the data from database through php to a blank div  name primaryy 
output show of the php is shown like this below
, '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'hdfgh' , 'ddd' , '' , 'Zanga' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'Susana' , '' , 'ghjgf' , '' , '' , '1212' , '2' , '' , '' , 'dfhg' , 'vcn' , '' , 'xcbxxb' , '' , '' , '' , 'Beathe' , 'Corredor' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'cvcxg' , '' , '' , '2' , 'ghjk' , 'level41' , '' , '' , ''

i remove the black ,'' with jquery and replace ' to " after that output will show like this below 
, "hdfgh" , "ddd" , "Zanga" , "Susana" , "ghjgf" , "1212" , "2" , "dfhg" , "vcn" , "xcbxxb" , "Beathe" , "Corredor" , "cvcxg" , "2" , "ghjk" , "level41"

if i pass it as a static in the source like source : ["option1","option2","option3"] in jquery then it will perform well but when i pass it through variable like source:[value15] then it will show one option like all show in the below
, "hdfgh" , "ddd" , "Zanga" , "Susana" , "ghjgf" , "1212" , "2" , "dfhg" , "vcn" , "xcbxxb" , "Beathe" , "Corredor" , "cvcxg" , "2" , "ghjk" , "level41" 
but i want show it separatly like this when i enter the innput like hdf then suggestion option will show hdfgh which is in the above options

Can anyone help me

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#primaryy').text( jQuery('#primaryy').text().replace(/\'/g, '"') );
    jQuery('#primaryy').text( jQuery('#primaryy').text().replace(/\, ""/g, '') );
 
    var value14 =   jQuery("#primaryy").text();
    
    var value15 = value14;
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#washer_92").autocomplete({
            source: [value15],
            select: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
               
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
    <div id="primaryy" class="content-area">
   <table border="1">
   <?php 
         global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM aves_postmeta where meta_key ='4_level_first'");
foreach($result as $print){
$dbdata=$print->meta_value; ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo ", '".$dbdata."' "; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
  ?></div></div>
<input type="text" id="washer_92">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are passing the input value as source which will get you nowhere because that is essentially unset the first time your page loads and that is also not calling your ajax handle to perform any database operation.
To resolve this change your code as mentioned below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function splitsource( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return splitsource( term ).pop();
    }
    $('#primaryy').on('keypress', function(event) {
        if ( (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB || event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) && $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#primaryy').text( jQuery('#primaryy').text().replace(/\'/g, '"') );
        $('#primaryy').text( jQuery('#primaryy').text().replace(/\, ""/g, '') );
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                $.getJSON( ajax_object.ajax_url+"?action=search_names&term="+re, function(data){
                    response($.map(data, function (v, i) {
                            return {
                                label: v.value,
                                value: v.value,
                                id: v.id
                            };
                        }));
                } );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui){
                //Perform any custom action that you might want on the keyword being selected.                          
            },
            minLength: 3,
            classes: {
                "ui-autocomplete": 'primaryy-custom-combobox-menu'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please note that you should have an ajax handle registered as search_names and there you should perform the necessary database operations and return the results to your autocomplete function in js file.

Comment: thank for your response Fahan , actually i fetch the data for php to a blank div name **primaryy** output show of the php is shown like this below

Comment: **, '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'hdfgh' , 'ddd' , '' , 'Zanga' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'Susana' , '' , 'ghjgf' , '' , '' , '1212' , '2' , '' , '' , 'dfhg' , 'vcn' , '' , 'xcbxxb' , '' , '' , '' , 'Beathe' , 'Corredor' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , '' , 'cvcxg' , '' , '' , '2' , 'ghjk' , 'level41' , '' , '' , ''**

Comment: if i pass it as a static in the sorce like source : ["option1","option2","option3"] in jquery then it will perform well but when i pass it through variable then it will show one option like all show in the above 
hope you get that all

Comment: see the above description again Thankyou

Comment: Do this `value15 = value15.split(",");` and pass to source as `value15` instead of `[value15]`

Comment: Glad to hear that!!